# Criar um pdf no android

Tags: android, pdf

Tenho um byte[] que é um pdf.
uso a seguinte classe pra tentar converter ele.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste);

    byte[] bytes = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("pdf");

    String fileName = "out.pdf";
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    try {
        // Create file
        File someFile = new File(filePath, fileName);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
        fos.write(bytes);


        Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(someFile), "application/pdf");
        target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Não foi possível abrir", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Mas quando vou abrir no leitor de pdf diz que o arquivo está corrompido ou danificado.

Comment: Navegando pelo gerenciador de arquivos do celular, você encontrou o pdf criado?

Comment: Não consigo achar a pasta do app no emulador

Comment: Verifica se você ta com permissões de `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ` e `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE `

Comment: está com as permissões garantidas

Comment: mudei a pasta de destino para o cartão sd, ai diz que o pdf está corrompido

Comment: Pode ser permissão das seguranças do Android, tente utilizar as seguintes linhas de código: `String fileName = "fileName.pdf"; File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);` talvez utilizando o `Environment` de certo

Comment: @Gaspar fiz assim mas na hora de abrir diz que o documento está danificado ou corrompido

Comment: eu não entendi a linha `byte[] bytes = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("pdf");` o `getIntent()` pega a Intent da Activity atual, talvez você precise puxar a intent de um método externo, verifique [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48914651/3681565)

Comment: @Gaspar essa linha tá certa, ele pega o byte[] da activity anterior. Atualizei a pergunta com o novo código

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvido de uma maneira simples. O Código estava praticamente certo, só faltava o decode pra base64.
Adicionei essa linha depois de pegar o byte[] da activity anterior

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: que bom, obrigado por compartilhar a resposta